# Chrome extension to bookmark and then close all bookmarked tabs

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I'm looking for an addon that does pretty much the same as [OneTab](https://www.one-tab.com/) but uses the default Chrome bookmark mechanism. (I like the new enhanced Chrome bookmark manager together with its sync functionality.)

For example, it'll create a folder (named after the current date-time) for all open tabs, and then close them, and open the bookmark manager tab (or keep it if it was already open).

Some similar tried addons that do not provide this functionality:

- [TabHamster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabhamster/mkfjjmjmnplabnplceaekkjcmdddokee?hl=en)
- [Bookmark My Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-my-tabs/dkcdcmananochmgmhgkhhmgegdnkgejl?hl=en)
- [Neater Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neater-bookmarks/ofgjggbjanlhbgaemjbkiegeebmccifi?hl=en)
- [Bookmarks Menu](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-menu/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi?hl=en)
- [Open Bookmark Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-bookmark-manager/oalceheiomajabalbakkoeiheiokhdbd?hl=en)
- [TooManyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp?hl=en)
- [Goomarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/goomarks-browser-for-goog/oknllbfkmapccinochelgmcdjhlgfnik?hl=en-GB)
- [Papaly Bookmark Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/papaly-bookmark-manager/ebaemiclbgheekdodbcengpahonmfnla?hl=en)
- [Bookmax](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmax-bookmark-manager/ofjpkfadmfhloombfmmlllnbhkoehckm?hl=en)
- [Qileke Navigation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%A5%87%E4%B9%90%E5%AF%BC%E8%88%AA%E4%B9%A6%E7%AD%BE%E6%94%B6%E8%97%8F%E5%A4%B9/knonabememjckhaegfobimbmbdnidlpk?hl=en)
- [Dewey Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dewey-bookmarks/aahpfefkmihhdabllidnlipghcjgpkdm?hl=en)